# Loading component appears on top of the page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I implemented a loading screen using a loader component on `_app.js`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url) => {
    setLoading(true)
  })
  Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', (url) => {
    setLoading(false)
  })
  return(
    <>
     ..<Head> <meta> tags here..
     {loading && <Loader />}
       <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </>
   )
 }
```

The problem is, although the loader component `<Loader/>` appears, when I scroll down, the page's content represented by `<Component {...pageProps} />;` can still be seen. This would break the purpose of the loader component. I'm supposed to only see the loader component while the page is still rendering.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use `ternary operator`  `loading ? <Loader /> : <Component {...pageProps} />` so when loading is true will be render `Loader` component, else when the loading is false then will be render `Component`.
Full code in below:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url) => {
    setLoading(true)
  })
  Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', (url) => {
    setLoading(false)
  })
  return(
    <>
     ..<Head> <meta> tags here..
     {loading ? <Loader /> : <Component {...pageProps} />}
    </>
   )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try ternary condition for  component. Check If ***loading*** is true then display ***Loader*** component else display ***<Component {...pageProps} />*** .

```
return(
  <>
   {loading ? <Loader /> : <Component {...pageProps} />}
  </>
)
```